# MySQL lost after upgrading to Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard

Continuing a question started at StackOverflow - this was more of an administrative question.

I made a silly mistake of upgrading Leopard a tad too soon.

I thought I dumped my mysql files but the last backup is about a month old.

Now I upgraded the computer to Snow Leopard, and trying to run the old mysql server wasn't happening. So I read you must reinstall mysql with a newer version which I did and it ran just fine and starts up just fine.

However - it seems it setup a new install, but since the older version cannot run on this platform - how can I dump the old data?

**update**:
A user has helped me get to the data file and try and copy the folders inside there.
I've done this with a few folders, and the items show up when i launch mysql, but its having permission errors (13) when I try to select a table.

```
Can't read dir of './compass/' (errno: 13)
```

Anything I try isn't working. Hopefully someone here can help.
Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 1):

This has been one of my annoyances with the migration assistant in MacOS X (even in server) - it just doesn't move the databases.

I wouldn't move the whole directory (/var/mysql), but I've had good luck pulling the individual directories in there named after the databases that you created.  Bring back up the service, then you'll have to recreate the permissions.  You don't need to issue a 'create database' before moving the directories in -- they'll be found when you start the service back up.

If you're not sure what the file permissions & ownership need to be, go from a clean install, and do a 'create database' and 'create table' so you can then see what it permissions the new install is setting.

If you're not sure what the database permissions were that you had, you could try renaming the old 'mysql' data directory, so it's available under another name for you to examine -- but *do*not* just move in the 'mysql' directory like you might others -- some of the security stuff is handled differently between mysql versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have 0 experience w/snow leopard but can you see if the data/directory has the appropriate permissions for the mysql user?

Comment: i believe it has the appropriate permissions. _mysql user is the only user that can read/write. so, whats happening now - is mysql is able to see the db, but when i try to select the table it says the table isnt there.